# Type mismatch: found String, required io.gatling.core.validation.Validation[String]

Tags: scala, gatling

Disclaimer: I'm not that familiar with Scala, so I'm probably doing something stupid.

We're using Gatling for our performance tests.  I'm currently trying to get it to submit a POST request to our API, using something like the following:

```
exec(http("post request")
  .post("http://ourApi")
  .body(
      StringBody(
          session => """{ "myContent": "value" }""" // 1
      )
  )
  .asJSON
  .check(status.is(200))
)
```

As you can see, I'm using an expression function for the `StringBody` at the line labelled `// 1`, which should be possible [according to the Gatling documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.5/http/http_request.html#request-body).

When I try to run that, however, I get a ZincCompiler error on that exact line:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : String("{ \"myContent\": \"value\" }")
 required: io.gatling.core.validation.Validation[String]
```

Why is it expecting a `Validation[String]`? In the documentation I only see strings as well...

Comment: We need to see your imports. Did you include `import io.gatling.core.Predef._` ?

Comment: @Ivan You should post this as an answer, not a comment, as it's most likely the right one.

Comment: That seems to be it @IvanBalashov, guess it really is time to fix my broken IDE... Any pointers on what that imports and how it somehow magically transforms my String to the correct type? I'd love to know how it actually works in Scala...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you linked says

> Expression
>
> Most Gatling DSL methods actually takes Expression[T] parameters, which is a type alias for Session => Validation[T].
>
> How is it that one can also pass Strings and other values then?
>
> The reason is that there are implicit conversions:
>
> - when passing a String, it gets automagically parsed turn them into Expressions thanks to Gatling EL compiler.
> - when passing a value of another type, it gets automagically wrapped into an Expression that will always return this static value.

So the problem is that the implicit conversion isn't getting triggered for some reason. From http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/session/validation.html#validation, you can try:

1. Add `import io.gatling.commons.validation._`.
2. If that doesn't help, use `Success("""{ "myContent": "value" }""")` explicitly.

Comment: The import should be `import io.gatling.commons.validation._`

Comment: I just noticed I never accepted this as the correct answer. I have now, enjoy the internet points ;)